# How to fix domain/default pair error for info.plist?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

After trying to run my app, I ran into a problem that I believe is for my info.plist. I am not using Firebase or anything and this is a very simple app. Additionally, I am having the same problem with all my previous projects too. I also ran flutter doctor -v and there were no reported problems and everything is up-to-date. I have included the error message that I keep getting. Any help would be much appreciated.

Additionally, I tried to look up the problem on GitHub; however, the results that I was getting were not much help. I did try to make sure the key and value I had were compatible with each other in my info.plist within Android Studio.

[Error I get after each run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV6yc.png)